# how to specify multiple restiction values in connection.Getschema in c sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

i used
  `odbcConnection.Getschema("Columns",new string[]{null,null,"Table1"})`

to get the column names of a Table 'Table1' 
now how do i specify multiple tables in the restriction in this function call to get list for multiple tables?
 and also is there any way to say to get the info for all tables except Table1(not operator)

Answer (score 0):

You could not get the table schema for multiple special tables. You could call

```
odbcConnection.GetSchema("Columns",new string[]{"catalog1", "owner1"})
```

to get all tables' schema in catalog1.owner1. And then, you need to find what you want manually.