# Add multiple restrictions to OdbcConnection.GetSchema

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

Is there a way to add multiple restrictions to a `GetSchema` call? There is nothing in the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that indicates that I can do so.

I want to take this:

```
OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, "SYS" });
OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, "DBSYS" });
OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, "MDSYS" });
```

And make it into this:

```
OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, "SYS,DBSYS,MDSYS" });
```

Or something similar. Is that possible? It would be even better if I could somehow request the inverse of those restrictions. So (the following won't be syntactically correct):

```
OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, !"SYS,DBSYS,MDSYS" });
// notice the ! operator in front of the restriction string
```

For reference, SYS/DBSYS/MDSYS are Oracle system schemas. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006991/how-to-specify-multiple-restiction-values-in-connection-getschema-in-c-sharp) but I figured I'd give it another shot for another opinion.